# PhotoRec extension customization is taking parts not defined in the signature

Tags: files, matlab, testdisk, photorec

when i tried to recover my .m files which are considered as .txt for photorec. I tried to add my own extension. After creating .m file containing the word **tic**  while in the .photorec.sig file i added the following line

```
m 0 "tic"
```

it returns all files that begin with tic even if there is somthing else written after the  word tic is the same line. I want to know if is there any way to seek for files without signature offset. For instance i want to seek for the word **imread**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working through a similar issue that required me to create my own .sig file. The best sources I have found are:

1. [Add your own extension to PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Add_your_own_extension_to_PhotoRec)
2. [Autopsy User Documentation  4.1](https://sleuthkit.org/autopsy/docs/user-docs/4.1/photorec_carver_page.html)

In the first article it mentions using hexdump which is apart of "bsdmainutils" package. Use that to extract the hex representation of the file for a better match.

Ex: (I had to recover some MySQL DB files)

```
hexdump -C mysql-recovery/some-one-might-get-fired.myd | head
```

it will dump

```
00000000  03 0a b4 00 5d ca f4 ef  f9 ff f7 ef 46 af 51 fc  |....].......F.Q.|
00000010  ff 03 08 79 e2 fa 81 b6  ff ff ff 4b 85 53 fd f6  |...y.......K.S..|
00000020  ff ff dd bb fa f1 3c 00  dc ff ac ff 7f fb 7f bd  |......<.........|
00000030  f8 01 7f 7a ff ff 5b fe  7f 63 00 0c 8f fe db fb  |...z..[..c......|
00000040  ff 07 31 10 ec dd 33 09  00 00 01 31 00 00 00 03  |..1...3....1....|
```

I take only the first line but in some cases (see link 1) you might need a portion of the second line or other cases you will have to skip the first lines completely to find a pattern further down to properly identify the file.

For example an .idb file has the following header but with idb files the first rows are different from what I gather. So I need an offset to get to the portion of the file that has a signature that is the same across multiple idb files.

```
hexdump -s 0 -C mysql-recovery/users.ibd | head
```

```
00000000  c7 60 ef 59 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.`.Y............|
00000010  00 00 1b 32 0c 91 bd 99  00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...2............|
00000020  00 00 00 00 01 11 00 00  01 11 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  14 00 00 00 12 40 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 38 00 00  |.....@.......8..|
00000040  00 01 00 00 00 00 0b b6  00 00 00 00 0b b6 00 00  |................|
00000050  00 03 00 00 00 00 01 16  00 00 00 00 00 9e 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00  ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 0b 00 00  00 00 ff ff ff ff 00 00  |................|
00000080  ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00  00 01 00 00 00 02 00 26  |...............&|
00000090  00 00 00 02 00 26 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.....&..........|
```

The last two lines here are what I need based on comparisons that I have made looking at other .idb files. Count each pair of numbers as one and that is your offset. To test I run

```
hexdump -s 128 -C mysql-recovery/users.ibd | head
```

```
00000080  ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00  00 01 00 00 00 02 00 26  |...............&|
00000090  00 00 00 02 00 26 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.....&..........|
000000a0  00 00 00 c6 ff ff ff ff  00 00 00 00 00 02 aa aa  |................|
000000b0  ea ff ff ab ff bf ff bf  ff ef ff ff fb fe 00 00  |................|
000000c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 01 16 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000d0  00 9e 00 00 00 02 bf ff  fa fb ff bf ef ef bf ab  |................|
000000e0  bf be fe ff ef fe 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00  |................|
000000f0  00 00 02 ce 00 00 00 00  09 5e 00 00 00 04 aa aa  |.........^......|
00000100  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa ab  aa ba aa aa aa aa 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 ff ff  ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

My .photorec.sig file looks like this for .myd and .idb file types.

```
myd 0 0x030ab4005dcaf4eff9fff7ef46af51fc
idb 128 0xffffffff000000000001000000020026
```

The recovered file still needs to be tested but this is how I added a custom sig for the file type. I hope this helps others and please make corrections and I will edit the post.